# Trying to Import Infoblox Module in Python

Tags: python, infoblox

I am trying to write some code in python to retrieve some data from Infoblox. To do this i need to Import the Infoblox Module.

Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: Do you mean this one ? https://github.com/Infoblox-Development/Infoblox-API-Python

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial

Comment: This question is rather unclear.  There are at least two different Python Infoblox libraries in the wild.  One of them hasn't seen a commit in over seven years.  Please be specific about what you tried

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
import infoblox
```

[infoblox info](https://github.com/Infoblox-Development/Infoblox-API-Python)

Comment: FYI, it's been over five years since someone made a commit to the [infoblox API](https://github.com/Infoblox-Development/Infoblox-API-Python) you recommend; most people would say that's an abandoned API... don't use it

Answer (score -1):

Before you can import infoblox you need to install it:

- open a command prompt (press windows button, then type cmd)
- if you are working in a virtual environment access it with `activate yourenvname` (otherwise skip this step)
- execute `pip install infoblox` to install infoblox, then you should be fine
- to test it from the command prompt, execute `python`, and then try executing `import infoblox`

The same process works for basically every package.

Comment: FYI, it's been over five years since someone made a commit to the [infoblox API](https://github.com/Infoblox-Development/Infoblox-API-Python) you recommend; most people would say that's an abandoned API... don't use it